# jQuery: keyup(): Update div with content from text area... line breaks?

Tags: jquery, line-breaks, key-events

I have posted a working version here: http://jsfiddle.net/JV2qW/2/

I have a textarea that updates (on `keyup()`) a div with the text that is being entered. Everything is working as it should, except the line breaks are not being recognized.

the html:

```
<p>enter text</p>
<textarea id='text'></textarea>
<div id='target'></div>
```

and the jquery:

```
$('#text').keyup(function(){
      var keyed = $(this).val();
      $("#target").html(keyed);
 });
```

Any thoughts on how to get the `\n` translated to `<br/>` or `<p>` tags?

many thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can replace any newlines with `<br/>`

```
$('#text').keyup(function() {
    var keyed = $(this).val().replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
    $("#target").html(keyed);
});
```

You can look into the MDC article about RegEx if you want to replace other things.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/omnosis/8XL7n/

replace the `'\n'` to `'<br />'`

Comment: Your fiddle only replaces the first \n

Comment: thanks for the guidance. this only works on the first instance of the \n

Answer (score 0):

Why don't You just do replace on keyed value and replace it?

Here You have example - section Convert carrage returns

http://lawrence.ecorp.net/inet/samples/regexp-format.php